# Can I add a second network adapter to my Azure VM?

Tags: networking, virtual-machines, azure

I have Multiple VM's on Windows Azure. Default, they come with 1 network adapter and you can only assign 1 virtual network (Availability Set)

My question is : possible to connect 1 VM to more then 1 virtual network (By adding a second network adapter for example)?

Thanks!

Comment: Neil Mackenzie has answered the question, but it's worth noting that you can link VNets together, which may achieve what you're looking for: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-configure-vnet-to-vnet-connection/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Each Windows Azure VM has a single NIC. A VM can be in only one VNET.

Note that an availability set is different from a VNET. An availability set is a way to group VMs in a way that they are not subject to a single point of failure - think putting VMs into different racks. A VNET is a virtual network

Comment: This is not actual information anymore. See documentation: https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-multiple-nics/

Answer (score 6):

As of October 2014, Multiple NICs are now supported in Azure:  http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/30/multiple-vm-nics-and-network-virtual-appliances-in-azure/

Answer (score 0):

As May 22, 2014, this is "This is currently under development!".

No ETA provided.

Source:

http://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking-dns-traffic-manager-vpn-vnet/suggestions/3144627-multiple-network-interface-cards-on-vm