# Multiple Domain names, Multiple Certificates, one IIS 7 server

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate

I have 1 IIS server that is hosting 3 domains, for example, example1.com, example2.com and example3.com. Each has it's own certificate. How can I install a separate certificate for each of these sites on IIS 7.5 ?

Currently using a UUC certificate with multiple domains on it is not an option.

Comment: What research have you done? What have you tried?

Comment: I've looked through many articles on this site and MSDN

http://serverfault.com/questions/284699/setup-iis-7-5-with-multiple-website-bindings-and-ssl

I've setup many other production servers using this setup with wildcard certs, but I've never done it with multiple certs and compleatly different domain names.

Answer (score 1):

Just install them and select "SNI" (Server Name Indication) and enter the hostname.

Edit: SNI is an IIS8 feature. For 7.5 see:
[Setup IIS 7.5 with multiple website bindings and SSL?](https://serverfault.com/questions/284699/setup-iis-7-5-with-multiple-website-bindings-and-ssl)

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I thought this was only an IIS 8 feature? I'm using 7.5.

Comment: Also we're not using a Wildcard certificate.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. You need IIS8 for that. See this then:
http://serverfault.com/questions/284699/setup-iis-7-5-with-multiple-website-bindings-and-ssl

Comment: that uses a wildcard certificate and different subdomains, the root level domain is still the same.

Comment: I'm using virtual hardware, is there anyway I could add IP's to the server and pull this off?

Comment: It is not possible using IIS7.5. The only possibilities are wildcard/SAN or differnet IP/Port combination per Certificate

Comment: Yes, with additional IP's it's possible

Comment: Heh Scratch that apprently you can't add a second nic in azure

http://serverfault.com/questions/565675/can-i-add-a-second-network-adapter-to-my-azure-vm

I think I may have to use a UCC certificate to solve this issue. 

thanks for your help MichelZ

Comment: We went with a UCC certificate and we were able to solve the issue.